# Javascript - Aparecer conteudo do bloco e sumir do restante

Tags: javascript

Tem 3 botões e abaixo de cada botão tem um texto que irá sumir e aparecer respectivo para cada botão. Porém ao clicar no botão 1, aparece o texto abaixo dele e some do restante. E assim por diante.

Como posso fazer isso?

Eu tentei pelo toggle, porém não some dos outros botões.

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
let texto = document.querySelectorAll(".texto");

for (let index = 0; index < buttons.length; index++) {
  buttons[index].addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (!texto[index].classList.contains('hide')) {
      texto[index].classList.remove('hide')
    } else {
      texto[index].classList.add('hide')
    }
    texto[index].classList.toggle('hide');
  })

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="espaco">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Botão 1</button>
    <p class="texto hide">Botão Teste 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="espaco">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Botão 2</button>
    <p class="texto hide">Botão Teste 1</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Imagem do Exemplo aqui:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyUjs.gif)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Olá, Jonathan! Você poderia criar uma função para cada botão:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Texto dos botões</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="botoes">
        <button onclick="txtbtn1()">Botão 1</button>
        <p id="texto1"></p>
        <button onclick="txtbtn2()">Botão 2</button>
        <p id="texto2"></p>
        <button onclick="txtbtn3()">Botão 3</button>
        <p id="texto3"></p>
    </div>
    <script>
        function txtbtn1() {
            let txt = document.getElementById('texto1')
            txt.innerHTML = 'Texto do botão 1'
        }
        function txtbtn2() {
            let txt = document.getElementById('texto2')
            txt.innerHTML = 'Texto do botão 2'
        }
        function txtbtn3() {
            let txt = document.getElementById('texto3')
            txt.innerHTML = 'Texto do botão 3'
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Opa obrigado pelo feedback, mas não é bem isso, pois quando eu clico no botão 2 não somem o conteúdo do botão 1 e 3 entende. E outra coisa, não quero ter que mencionar cada botão que eu tenha adicionado novo. Que ele leia o array por completo e conclua a regra.

Comment: e se tivessem 50 botões ia criar 50 funções?

Answer (score -1):

Resolvi! Usando ForEach.

```
for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  const botao = btn[i];
  botao.addEventListener('click', function () {
    text.forEach(element => {
      if (!element.classList.contains('hide')) {
        element.classList.add('hide');
      }
    });
    text[i].classList.toggle('hide')
  })
}
```